# Weird Switch Statement Bug

Tags: java, debugging, switch-statement

```
choice = UserInput.validString();

while(ValidOption == false){            
    switch(choice){
        case  "y": 
            ValidOption = true; 
            roll();
            break;

        case "n": 
            ValidOption = true; 
            MainMenu.menu(); 
            break;

        default:  
            System.out.print("You must pick Y or N, try again : ");
            ValidOption = false; 
            choice = UserInput.eraseStringInput();
            break;
    }
} 
return; 
}
```

So when I press "y", my program will run the default case in my switch statement and then it will run the y case right after. This is my code. Why is it doing that?

Here is my validString method

```
public static String validString(){
    do {
        if(input.hasNext("\\p{Alpha}*")){
            s = input.nextLine();
            valildString  = true;
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print("You can only use letters, Try again :  ");
            input.next();
            valildString  = false;
        }
    } while (!(valildString ));

    return s;
}
```

**HERE IS A  PIC :** [1]: http://i58.tinypic.com/e6t9v6.png

Comment: Show us how you input `choice`.

Comment: I don't believe you. Post a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: thats the most of the section with what was asked for

Comment: `UserInput.validString()` doesn't seem to do what you think it does...

Comment: it worksin every other case, thats why im confused

Comment: i posted that method

Comment: Ahaha. You should use `s = input.next()` in the *if* part, and `nextLine()` in the `else` part. And after you get a proper `s` you should use `input.nextLine()` to clean the line, as I told you in the other question.

Comment: yup had it backwards lol thanks again man... im so nooby =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ways to read console inputs is to use Console or Scanner, so how are you getting the input?

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input choice (y/n): ");
String choice = console.nextLine();
```

--------- OR ---------

```
Console console = System.console();
String choice = console.readLine("Enter choice (y/n):");
```

and then use the switch case. If I'm reading your code correctly, there's not enough to really see what's going on completely.

EDIT: Change the if statement to read input.next(), and the else statement to read input.nextLine() - as per RealSkeptic

Comment: very similar to your first example

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the switch to see what is the value of 'choice' is?

Comment: yes and its coming back correct, =(

Comment: there is something wrong with my validString method, its not getting along with switches for some odd reason

Comment: RealSkeptic answered you in the comments. It's where you read the input in the ValidString method. Copied from comments: "Ahaha. You should use s input.next() in the if part, and nextLine() in the else part. And after you"

Comment: lol.. damn had it backwards yup that worked lol thanks -.-

Comment: Feel free to mark the question answered, and I'm glad it all worked out. Happy coding!